# Struggling to setup Dynamode wifi USB on OpenElec

Tags: networking, wifi, openelec

I bought a [Dynamode nano USB adapter](http://www.pifactory.co.za/download/file/fid/120) which I would like to use with my OpenElec (FRODO) Pi.

The Pi is able to connect to the internet using a LAN connection (using a static IP). When I try to use the wifi dongle, I am however not able to get it to connect to the internet.

I have tried the built-in settings as well as downloading [Network Manager](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Add-on:Network-Manager). This failed because I believe it is only on Ubuntu.

The configurations I have tested was both static and dynamic, and the info is correct.

Maybe this is a driver issue, but I have plugged in the dongle while an Ethernet cable is plugged into the Pi. Not sure if I perhaps have to run a command of some sort.

I have configured numerous devices to connect to a Wi-Fi network, but I am unable to accomplish this with the Pi. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you plug the Wi-Fi USB dongle into an _externally powered_ USB hub which is, in turn, connected to the RPi, does the issue persist? That is to say: Is it the typical lack of available current as [Steve suggests](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9688/struggling-to-setup-dynamode-wifi-usb-on-openelec#answer-9704), or; the OpenElec issue, as [suggested by UbanPykey](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9688/struggling-to-setup-dynamode-wifi-usb-on-openelec#answer-37993)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems with wifi dongles are usually down to a lack of power.  Is the wifi dongle connected to the Pi's USB socket, or is it connected to a USB hub?  The Pi's USB socket may not able to supply enough current to the wifi dongle.

Comment: the dongle is directly connect to the Pi. There is also no other USB devices connected to it. I use the XBMC Remote app to control the device.

Comment: You could try using different power supplies - you might get lucky.  The best thing to do would be try it with a powered USB hub. That way the dongle draws power from the hub's supply rather than the Pi's.

Answer (score 2):

On openelec if you have an Ethernet cable plugged in it will use that. It is only designed as a single network connection system. To get wireless to work you have to unplug the Ethernet.